# Access host service both using docker and using podman

Tags: docker, podman

Okay so I have a container `C` which needs to access a service on host `H`, `H` may run docker or it may run Podman. I do not have control over this, it is end-user choice.
Under docker I can have get `C` to access service on `H` using `host.docker.internal` and with Podman `host.containers.internal`.
But I cannot find a way to do it in an manner that works across both Docker and Podman, is there a way to do this?

Comment: I think both set an environment variable "container" and in podman it is set to "podman" if you are looking for a way to automatically switch configuration.

Comment: yeah... it just feels like a really bad hack to me